# Python parallel threads: progress bar for each thread

Tags: python, multithreading, progress-bar, tqdm

I am running in parallel the processing on several files. I would like to have a progress bar showing individual progress for each file. I could get the multi-threading to work on one side, and the progress bars on the other side. But I could not combine both.

For the progress bars I tried tqdm and alive_progress. I preferred alive_progress but tqdm seems to handle better multiple bars.

For the parallelization I tried concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor, concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor and multiprocessing.Pool.

The operation I want to parallelize:

```
from bitstring import ConstBitStream
import os
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

def read_file(input):
    filename, limit_packet, verbose = input
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        b = ConstBitStream(file)
        tot_len = len(b)
        with tqdm(total=tot_len, desc=f'Read {os.path.basename(filename)}', bar_format='{l_bar}{bar:24}{r_bar}{bar:-24b}') as pbar:
            while b.pos < tot_len
                initial_pos = b.pos

                # (...do stuff and advance b.pos...)

                pbar.update(b.pos - initial_pos)
```

The parallelization and how the progress bars work:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing as mp

# 25s, progress bars work (sequential)
for filename in filenames:
    read_file((filename, limit_packet, verbose))

# 90s, bars progress work during processing (each advances individually), but display is messed up at the end
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as p:
    p.map(read_file, tasks)

# 7s, progress bars don't work (erase each other)
with mp.Pool() as p:
    p.map(read_file, tasks)

# 7s, progress bars don't work (erase each other)
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as p:
    p.map(read_file, tasks)
```

The output:

```
Read APID1328_nominal.RAW: 100%|████████████████████████| 20350800/20350800 [00:01<00:00, 17251305.63it/s]                                                                                                           
Read APID1329_nominal.RAW: 100%|████████████████████████| 34371744/34371744 [00:00<00:00, 138007642.34it/s]                                                                                                          
Read APID1330_nominal.RAW: 100%|████████████████████████| 93211008/93211008 [00:01<00:00, 62731185.83it/s]                                                                                                           
Read APID1331_nominal.RAW: 100%|████████████████████████| 1981932480/1981932480 [00:04<00:00, 481080038.07it/s]                                                                                                      
Read APID1332_nominal.RAW: 100%|████████████████████████| 1981932480/1981932480 [00:04<00:00, 479111687.19it/s]                                                                                                      
Read APID1333_nominal.RAW: 100%|████████████████████████| 890472000/890472000 [00:03<00:00, 251308739.13it/s]                                                                                                        
Read APID1334_nominal.RAW: 100%|████████████████████████| 1905473856/1905473856 [00:05<00:00, 349347788.89it/s]                                                                                                      
Read APID1335_nominal.RAW: 100%|████████████████████████| 1333757568/1333757568 [00:01<00:00, 688773001.69it/s]                                                                                                      
Read APID1336_nominal.RAW: 100%|████████████████████████| 1316977728/1316977728 [00:01<00:00, 934369546.81it/s]
```

Answer (score 3):

This example will create a `multiprocessing.Pool` with 4 process that tries to process 10 files in total (the same idea applies to `ThreadPoolExecutor` etc.).

There is one auxiliary process that handles all `tqdm` bars and receives commands via `multiprocessing.Queue`. The worker processes sends to this queue various commands (`new`, `update` in this case) and the bar process handles them (creates new progress bar, update existing bar etc.):

```py
import time
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing


def bars(q):
    bars = {}

    while True:
        command, args = q.get()
        match command:
            case 'new':
                name, total_length = args
                bars[name] = tqdm(desc=name, total=total_length, position=len(bars))
            case 'update':
                name, how_much = args
                bars[name].update(how_much)
                bars[name].refresh()



def work_initializer(queue):
    global g_queue
    g_queue = queue


def work(filename):
    g_queue.put_nowait(('new', (str(filename), 10)))
    for _ in range(10):
        g_queue.put_nowait(('update', (str(filename), 1)))
        time.sleep(random.random() / 2)
    return f'{filename} OK'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    bar_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=bars, args=(bar_queue, ), daemon=True)
    bar_process.start()

    results = []
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4, initializer=work_initializer, initargs=(bar_queue, )) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(work, (f'filename_{i}.RAW' for i in range(10))):
            results.append(result)

    print('\n'*10, *results, sep='\n')
```

Prints (at the end of processing):

```
filename_0.RAW: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.41it/s]
filename_1.RAW: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:01<00:00,  8.28it/s]
filename_2.RAW: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.40it/s]
filename_3.RAW: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.10it/s]
filename_4.RAW: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.87it/s]
filename_5.RAW: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.62it/s]
filename_6.RAW: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:01<00:00,  5.51it/s]
filename_7.RAW: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  4.64it/s]
filename_8.RAW: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  4.08it/s]
filename_9.RAW: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.40it/s]

filename_1.RAW OK
filename_2.RAW OK
filename_3.RAW OK
filename_0.RAW OK
filename_6.RAW OK
filename_4.RAW OK
filename_7.RAW OK
filename_5.RAW OK
filename_8.RAW OK
filename_9.RAW OK
```